# Is there a more efficient way to dockerize Luarocks?

Tags: docker, google-cloud-build, luarocks

I am trying to build a lean alpine docker container for unit testing Lua in Google Cloud Build.

It runs fine, but takes about 30 - 50 seconds to build. When I run busted and luacheck, it only takes a few seconds for each. Any thoughts on how I could optimize this build process?

I was using wget and then switched to git. I added curl and unzip since luarocks expects it and openssl for one of luacheck's dependencies. Are there different dependencies I could/should use?

```
FROM alpine

ENV LUA_VERSION 5.1

RUN apk update

RUN apk add lua${LUA_VERSION} 
RUN apk add lua${LUA_VERSION}-dev

RUN apk add bash build-base curl git openssl unzip

RUN cd /tmp && \
    git clone https://github.com/keplerproject/luarocks.git && \
    cd luarocks && \
    sh ./configure && \
    make build install && \
    cd && \
    rm -rf /tmp/luarocks

RUN luarocks install busted
RUN luarocks install luacheck
RUN luarocks install luacov
```

Comment: what's changing between every build?

Comment: I am using the Google Cloud Build GitHub app and triggering it for "Push to branch". Is that what you mean?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

Dockerfile

```dockerfile
FROM alpine:3.12

# Set environment
ENV LUA_VERSION=5.1.5 \
    LUAROCKS_VERSION=3.4.0

# Install dependency packages
RUN set -xe && \
        apk add --no-cache --virtual .build-deps \
            curl \
            gcc \
            g++ \
            libc-dev \
            make \
            readline-dev \
        && \
        apk add --no-cache \
            readline \
        && \
        # Install Lua
        wget http://www.lua.org/ftp/lua-${LUA_VERSION}.tar.gz && \
        tar zxf lua-${LUA_VERSION}.tar.gz && rm -f lua-${LUA_VERSION}.tar.gz && \
        cd lua-${LUA_VERSION} && \
        make -j $(getconf _NPROCESSORS_ONLN) linux && make install && \
        cd / && rm -rf lua-${LUA_VERSION} && \
        # Install LuaRocks
        wget https://luarocks.org/releases/luarocks-${LUAROCKS_VERSION}.tar.gz && \
        tar zxf luarocks-${LUAROCKS_VERSION}.tar.gz && rm -f luarocks-${LUAROCKS_VERSION}.tar.gz && \
        cd luarocks-${LUAROCKS_VERSION} && \
        ./configure && \
        make -j $(getconf _NPROCESSORS_ONLN) build && make install && \
        cd / && rm -rf luarocks-${LUAROCKS_VERSION} && \
        # Remove all build deps
        apk del .build-deps && \
        # Test
        lua -v && luarocks

COPY docker-entrypoint.sh /usr/local/bin
```

docker-entrypoint.sh

```sh
#!/bin/sh

set -e

buildDepsApk="
curl
libc-dev
gcc
wget
"

pm='unknown'
if [ -e /lib/apk/db/installed ]; then
    pm='apk'
fi

if [ "$pm" = 'apk' ]; then
    apk add --no-cache ${buildDepsApk}
fi

luarocks install $@

if [ "$pm" = 'apk' ]; then
    apk del ${buildDepsApk}
fi
```

Answer (score -1):

You don't have to build *luarocks*. You can just install the package using,

```
RUN apk add luarocks
```

Comment: When I try this with nginx:1.21.1-alpine it runs, apparently, but I can't actually use it:
```
 => [ 2/14] RUN apk add luarocks                                                                                                                                                                       2.0s
 => ERROR [ 3/14] RUN luarocks install lunajson  
```